# hls video format is not working in angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I recently stuck in while playing videos in hls format. I have to show hls videos in front-end using angular and i had done some research and found hls.js to show videos.

i have tried below code but still getting blank response on video tag.

i am searching from last 4 hours. And still not found proper solution.

html file

```
<video id="active_video"></video>
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
```

typescript file

```
var video = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('active_video');
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource('https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8');
      hls.attachMedia(video);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
        video.play(); 
      });
    }
    else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      video.src = 'https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8';
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        video.play();
      });
    }
```

please let me know where i am going wrong and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-embed-video?

Comment: @siddharthshah i have tried but it's not working

Comment: can you try creating a demo on stackblitz